# Laravel 8 Migration - change enum values

Tags: laravel, enums, database-migration, laravel-8

I'm trying to change an enum value in database with Laravel migrations.

In first, i have tried this classic change :

```
Schema::table('questionnaires', function ($table) {
    $table->enum('type', ['image', 'sound', 'video'])->nullable()->default('image')->change();
});
```

But I got the following error :

> Unknown database type enum requested,
> Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it

I solved my problem by doing SQL directly :

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE questionnaires MODIFY COLUMN type ENUM('image', 'sound', 'video') DEFAULT 'image'");
```

But it does not seem optimal to me...

Is there a solution more in "agreement" with Laravel 8,
without going through pure SQL?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3161#issuecomment-542814085

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Explanation

To elaborate a little bit more on this subject.

As noted [here](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3819#issuecomment-573419808) ENUMs cannot be reverse engineered into a certain type. Each ENUM is a value of it's own. Hence, you must specifically say to Laravel which type the ENUMs are.

#### This seems to be an issue with all versions of Laravel

In documentation for each version, i.e. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#renaming-columns, you can find that changing enum fields is not supported. As noted [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unknown-database-type-enum-requested) the DB statement inside your migration is the best workaround for now.

```php
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE questionnaires MODIFY COLUMN type ENUM('image', 'sound', 'video') DEFAULT 'image'");
```

#### Migration files fix

This option is the above commented [GitHub link](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3161#issuecomment-542814085) which advises you to put this line of code before the actual migration inside `up()` method of migration file.

```php
DB::connection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
```

#### Models/enum types fix

I think this one is a lot less straightforward then the above mentioned, but still exists as a valid option, so I will put it here,

You can read an official doctrine-project website page [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-1-mapping-to-varchars) which shows you how to this thing from within models / enum types.

Comment: Thank you for your return. But with this, I have this error :
Unknown column type "enum" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap()

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Comment: I'm trying on Laravel 8.9. I also tried on a Laravel 6.6 with the same result

Comment: Yes, going through Laravel docs it seems that each version has this problem. Going with DB statements is the best workaround for now, I've updated my answer to point that out.